# Link State Pass-thru on eth0 and eth1 while bridging

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

Is there a way to control link state of an adjacent network adapter while configured as a bridge?

I'm using Debian 10 with interfaces file and creating `br0` from `enp1s0` and `enp2s0`.

I'd like to be able to prevent a link state from being up until the second Ethernet interface is connected, as well as take down the second Ethernet interface when the first is disconnected. I don't see a way to do this.

The desire is link state transparency. This would be useful to be in between interfaces between network switches. Or another interface and a switch. Where if unplugged on either end, the bridge would take down or put up both of it's interfaces.